# Clojure weird adding behavior

Tags: clojure

I'm new to clojure and learning basic built in functions. I noticed some weird error when summing values.

user=> (+ 0.99 10 10)
20.990000000000002

user=> (+ 0.99 30 10)
40.989999999999995

However, (+ 0.99 10 30) gives the expected result, 40.99. What do you think is causing this? I'm just using the terminal window on Mac and clj command for the clojure repl. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the same question as posted on Reddit (and answered there): https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/nia8lo/weird_partial_error/

Comment: Yes - I posted in both places, which turns out was unnecessary! Thanks again!